# Spring Kafka or Kafka streams for a high volume data processing Spring boot application

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am working on to create a high volume JSON data processing application for a bank using Spring boot, Kafka and QuickFIX/J. This is my first time play with technologies like Kafka and QuickFIX/J and unable to decide that should I use plain Kafka spring or Kafka streams or spring cloud streams.
Here is the requirement:

1. Read data from multiple Kafka topics
2. Process and send the data to a QuickFIX/J initiator that further sends it to an external FIX engine
3. A QuickFIX/J acceptor receives the data from external FIX engine and write it back again to multiple Kafka topics, but different ones this time

I have gone through tutorials/articles that say Kafka streams or spring cloud stream is good if you have both consumer/producer, performing high volume data streaming and want to achieve exactly once processing. But, here I need to send data to an external party after processing, receive it and then write to Kafka topics.

Is using Kafka stream a good choice? or shall I use spring kafka with normal producers & consumers?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Cloud Stream is just a higher level, opinionated, abstraction on top of Spring for Apache Kafka. It can handle your use case (there are several "sink" sample applications).

Similarly, Kafka Streams does not necessarily have to produce output to Kafka (although that's what it is designed to do).

Probably the fastest on-ramp is Spring Cloud Stream (or Spring for Apache Kafka with Spring Boot) because most cookie-cutter configuration is provided for you and you can just concentrate on your business logic.